# How to identify duplicates between 2 different sheets of same file in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns of data in Sheet 1 and two columns of data in Sheet 2. Now I want to find the duplicates between these two columns of different sheets using any formula.[image]

Comment: Use match() would be one way

Comment: what would your expected output looks like? and more importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SolarMike I have tried match but it only captures the sequential cell in the other sheet. Suppose it identifies the cell only in Row 2 for putting the formula in other sheet in Row 2. In the same way Row 3, 4.....

Comment: @TerryW my expected output would look like this, in the Sheet2, in any cell, I want excel to check an individual number with all the numbers in Sheet1 and return a text I make up in formula. Even better, if there is any formula for how many times it has been duplicated.

Comment: what version of Excel are you using? Have you ever used `#powerquery`?

Comment: Match() gives you the numerical position of the matching item.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is available in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

I used the following data for each range which is the same as your example except I added `1991082802` to Cell `B9` of `Range 1`.

```
| Range 1    |            |   | Range 2    |            |
|------------|------------|---|------------|------------|
| Column1    | Column2    |   | Column1    | Column2    |
| 1991082802 |            |   | 1991082802 | 1785867195 |
| 1758058397 | 1785850195 |   | 1758058397 | 1785850195 |
| 1629325544 | 1746402471 |   | 1629325545 | 1746402471 |
| 1884389479 | 1768735009 |   | 1884345479 |            |
| 1631642814 |            |   | 1631642814 |            |
| 1867744901 | 1719428447 |   | 1867744910 | 1719428447 |
| 1684430392 | 1991082802 |   | 1684431092 |            |
```

Steps are:

1. *Load* both ranges to the **Power Query Editor**;
2. Let's start with `Range1`, firstly, use **Merge Columns** function to combine both columns into one with delimiter colon sign `:`, then use **Split Columns** function to split this column by colon sign `:` and in the advanced settings choose to put the results into **Rows**, then *filter* out all the *`null`*, then make a duplicated column and use **Group By** function to count the number of duplicated rows by each number. Then you should have something like the following:

[image: Range1]

3. Do the same for `Range2` except there is no need to create a duplicated column to find the counts, but rather use **Merge Queries** function to merge `Range2` with `Range1`, and then expand the merged column to show `Count`, then you should have something like the following:

[image: Range2]

Renamed the columns as desired, and then **Close & Load** the output to a new worksheet (by default).

Here are the Power Query **M Codes** behind the scene. All steps are using GUI without advanced coding so should be quite easy and straight forward.

**Range1** codes:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}, "en-AU"),{"Column1", "Column2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Columns", {{"Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Merged"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Merged", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([Merged] <> null)),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Merged", "Merged - Copy"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Duplicated Column", {"Merged - Copy"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Range2** codes:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}, "en-AU"),{"Column1", "Column2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Merged Columns", {{"Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Merged"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Merged", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([Merged] <> null)),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows", {"Merged"}, Range1, {"Merged - Copy"}, "Range1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Range1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Range1", {"Count"}, {"Count"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Range1",{{"Merged", "Range2"}, {"Count", "No. of Duplications from Range1"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)